# Print Current view in Google Map API v3 with Marker And Polygon

Tags: printing, dictionary, polygon, marker

I'm facing problem in google map v3 API
I'm trying to print the current view of my map including marker and polygon shape

I want to have on link which allow me to print current view of the map including marker and polygon shape

**currently I'm using this way**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myPrint('map');">Print Map</a>
```

**and this is the function**

```
function myPrint(id){
    w=window.open();
    w.document.write($('#'+id).html());
    w.print();
}
```

but it's only print the current view but without marker and polygon

Please help me to find solution for this

Thanks alot :)